# How can I integrate AdWords conversion with Contact form?

Tags: contao

I wan to integrate an AdWords conversion code in contao. The conversion shall be tracked when a contact form (that was created in the Backend) is sent successfully. I've to do that for a costumer of my organization and actually got no experiences with contao. I already generated the conversion code, I just don't know the "place" to paste it. Is there a template or sth. like that for each form?

Comment: Hi Nick, Have you solved this issue? If not I'll give it a whack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are different ways to achieve this in contao.

first you could copy the templates to to your /template folder and add the code

second, an much easier solution, you could create an html-module (in the layout section) an include it as a content element in the frontent (i would say on the page where's the form redirect)